# why does BLANK android application's Heap Alloc keep increasing?

Tags: android, garbage-collection

I'm tracing a heap size increasing problem of my own app and found this:
An android application's Heap Alloc keeps increasing without doing anything, here is part of my test code:

```
package com.example.zqw;
import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.IBinder;

public class MainActivity extends Service {
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

I'm using `am startservice` to start this application which only have one blank service above.
And using `dumpsys meminfo com.example.zqw` to view the Heap Alloc of Dalvik Heap which **keeps increasing** until GC triggers.

I'm testing this on my Samsung / Lenovo devices of different models. The only difference is when the GC triggers: 12M 18M 21M ...

You can try this on your own device, and I'm pretty sure you'll find the same thing happens.

Anyone knows why?

Comment: After GC triggers, does memory use go down or not? In any case, you can use DDMS's allocation tracker to see allocating call stacks in the app.

Comment: After GC triggers, memory use goes down. No memory leaks occurred.

Comment: Did you use the allocation tracker to figure out what is causing the allocs?